# "Rectangle cannot be converted to bounds" using rectangle.intersect()?

Tags: java, javafx, rectangles, scene

So I am passing double values from a rectangle to see if it intersects with a different rectangle.  I pass the attribute values (x, y, w, h) as arguments to the function, then create a rectangle within it and set the argument as its attributes.  I then I test it using the `rectangle.intersects(rect)` to see if they overlap.  The code is below.

**THE PROBLEM:**  The line `inputRectangle.intersects(scannedRectangle);` is giving an error that says `"Incompatible types: Rectangle cannot be converted to bounds`.

A Google and SO search had no results for that error.

How am I going about this incorrectly?  Thanks

```
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
-----------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^------------

public boolean isIntersectingNode(double inputX, double inputY, double inputWidth, double inputHeight)
{

    Rectangle inputRectangle = new Rectangle(inputX, inputY, inputWidth, inputHeight);
    double newX = 20, newY = 20, newW = 20, newH = 20;

    Rectangle scannedRectangle = new Rectangle(newX, newY, newW, newH);

    return inputRectangle.intersects(scannedRectangle);  <<<<<<<ERROR HERE

}
```

NOTE:  I simplified the code somewhat.  But no matter how I change the code, the `scannedRectangle` segment in the function is giving that error.

Comment: this would'nt have happened if you had used a proper IDE (like Eclipse) because these always show a parameter list .... just saying - programming without proper IDEs is like driving without car interior and selfmade, wooden tools as control mechanics

Comment: @specializt I'm actually using NetBeans.  I use Eclipse too.  It really depends on what I'm doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle` is a `Node`. Since you're not using those objects as parts of a scene, you're better off using [`javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/geometry/Rectangle2D.html) to check for intersections. This class does not extend `Node` and it allows you to check 2 `Rectangle2D`s for intersection.

```
public boolean isIntersectingNode(double inputX,
                                  double inputY,
                                  double inputWidth,
                                  double inputHeight) {

    Rectangle2D inputRectangle = new Rectangle2D(inputX, inputY, inputWidth, inputHeight);
    double newX = 20, newY = 20, newW = 20, newH = 20;

    Rectangle2D scannedRectangle = new Rectangle2D(newX, newY, newW, newH);

    return inputRectangle.intersects(scannedRectangle);
}
```

Comment: In the full program, the "rectangle" that the double values are coming from is a label/node.  That's why I'm creating rectangles within the function, so I have two rectangles to compare.  Seemed like an easy way to compare 2 node locations.

Comment: Using `Rectangle2D` did it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that [intersects()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#intersects-javafx.geometry.Bounds-) requires an object of type `Bounds` as parameter. A `Rectangle` does not inherit from `Bounds` and hence cannot be used here. You may want to try one of the [`getBounds...()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getBoundsInParent--) methods to get the bounds to then intersect.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because [`Node.intersects`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#intersects-javafx.geometry.Bounds-) accepts a [`Bounds`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/geometry/Bounds.html) objects as input argument:

```
public boolean intersects(Bounds localBounds)
```

> Returns true if the given bounds (specified in the local coordinate
>   space of this Node) intersects the shape of this Node.

On other hand, in your `isIntersectingNode` method you do not add the `Rectangle` instances to the scene graph, therefore it is impossible to check for intersection as they have no coordinate space.

As a solution, you can use the original `Rectangle` object, which one is attached to the scene-graph and execute for example:

```
 rect.getBoundsInParent().intersects(x, y, w, h);
```